# Why did removing my non-upvoted answer take away 8 rep?

Tags: support

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26393543/1624318) was the answer, which I undeleted in case viewing it helps but will delete again after I resolve this because it had no value in 2014, much less 2017.

I know we lose rep for deleting upvoted or accepted answers, but I don't understand why this answer mattered in any way.

Comment: It *is* upvoted. It has an upvote and a downvote. + 10 rep - 2 rep = 8 total rep and a score of 0.

Comment: OH. I'm assuming that rep's not retrievable, right? Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: Well if you delete it again, you'll lose it again. It's already been added back to your reputation now because you undeleted it.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I see it now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That answer isn't non-voted. It has one upvote (+10 rep) and one downvote (-2 rep), for a net total of +8 rep.
Once you become an [Established User](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) (i.e., gain 1000 rep) you'll be able to see this breakdown yourself.